What are default colors for each Material 3 component in Jetpack Compose?
In Compose each material component has defaut color which is taken from material theme.
I don't want to provide custom color to each component and setup the theme instead.
Obviously you can see a source code, but it's a mess and it's very hard to find which color is actually used. There should be a resource where I can see this information, but I can't find it.
